Lenovo ideapad slim 5 (14AHP9) keyboard+touchpad not working
Trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my new IdeaPad slim 5.
Booting from usb, keyboard and touchpad not working. When mouse connected via usb - everything works fine.
There is no official drivers for linux, but maybe someone had the same issue and found ones that work?
